# Accessing TObject instance when it is locked by TMonitor.Enter in the calling thread

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

What will happen if a thread tries to access the same object locked by another thread?  I know it can be handled by `TMonitor.Wait()`, but what if there is no handling codes to check if it is locked?  Will there be an error?

In the example below, `Thread1Process` locks the object and `Thread2Process` attempts to assign a value to the object's property.  Will the `Thread2Process` automatically wait before `Thread1Process` releases the lock to execute the next line `var x: Integer := 1;` or will it stop and throw an exception?

```
procedure Thread1Process(const AObject: TObjectDescendant);
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(AObject);
  try
    // lengthy process here...
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(AObject);
  end;
end;

procedure Thread2Process(const AObject: TObjectDescendant);
begin
  AObject.StringProperty := 'Any value';
  var x: Integer := 1;
end;
```

We are using Delphi 11 Alexandria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TMonitor` is just a synchronization lock, nothing more. Much like `TMutex`, `TSemaphore`, etc.

It doesn't do anything to the object itself.  If one thread decides to enter the lock, and a second thread doesn't, the second thread will not be blocked in any way, and no exception will be raised <sup>1</sup>, but there is no guarantee to the stability of the object or its members.  Race conditions occur due to *lack* of proper synchronization by all involved threads cooperating with each other.

<sup>1</sup>: unless the object itself decides to raise an exception, or a system exception is raised, like from accessing invalid memory, etc.

---

On a side note, your call to `TMonitor.Enter()` needs to be outside the `try` block, eg:

```
procedure Thread1Process(const AObject: TObjectDescendant);
begin
  TMonitor.Enter(AObject);
  try
    // lengthy process here...
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(AObject);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am just wondering why Delphi's documentation of System.TMonitor.Enter says "Prohibits the access of all other threads but the calling one to the specified object."

Comment: @pcpestolante that only applies to the lock inside the object, not to the object itself. If threads don't agree to cooperatively share the same lock before accessing the object, then those threads are not blocked from accessing the object whenever they want, which can lead to race conditions and other undesirable side effects.

Comment: Thank you so much @Remy Lebeau. This helps a lot.